# The permissions granted to user 'domain\username' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

but i ReportServer web not listed in iis. this is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS 2008 does not have any dependencies on IIS anymore. so you cant see a web for report server in IIS.

SSRS 2008 doesn't support anonymous login , so to solve your permission problem have to Connect locally to the reporting services website. Select the folder you want to edit, then click the properties tab. Then select Security from the left. From there you can add the users or groups that you want to access the site